# Same primary key as Foreign Key for two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make three tables i.e `Provinces`, `Languages`, and `Cities`.

My `Provinces` and `Cities` use `Languages`. So I made join tables i.e `Provinces_Languages` and `Cities_Languages`. All tables contains `id` and `name` as columns.

**Provinces**
id
name

**Languages**
id
name

**Provinces_Languages**
province_id
languages_id

**Foreign Keys**
         [image]

Similarly for cities:

**Cities**
id
name

**Using same Languages Table**

**Cities_Languages**
cities_id
languages_id

**Foreign Keys**

[image]

However, it can't use the same primary key from language the table. I am getting this error:

[image]

How i can resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you make your alter statements more simple and add/drop one thing at a time so your table will look like what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a constraint called FK_Language. Use a different name

Answer (score 1):

`FK_Language` exists already when you try to create it again.

You should create separate alter table statements, making sure that the `FK` get's dropped before you create it again.

**Basically:** You try to drop the `FK` and create it again at the same time, that won't work.

By the way, you should be consistent on whether to use `Cities_Languages` or `langauges_cities`.